# How to add new variables generated using CLO and ALR back to the original dataset using R

Tags: r

So I have an existing dataset and from that, I have converted three variables into a budget composition using `clo`. I then convert it into additive log ratios using `alr`.

```
(clo <- clo(mydata, parts=c("P","L", "I"), total=1) )

alr <- alr(clo, 2)*1000
```

I just wanted to find out how you can then add these new variables back into the original dataset?

Many thanks in advance,

Miriam

Comment: Please `dput(mydata[seq_len(min(nrow(mydata), 20)), ])` for us.

Comment: Thanks a lot Robert for responding to this. I type this command and get a stream of info summarising the data????? What I did was save it to a text doc, convert to excel, then copy to .dta using Stata. Then using the library(foreign) added back to R using the command [mydata = read.dta("20140703_5_publicspending_ALR.dta", convert.dates = TRUE, convert.factors = TRUE, missing.type = FALSE, convert.underscore = FALSE, warn.missing.labels = TRUE)] - Very long winded.